# Refresh page on button click in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using below code to refresh the page. However when moving the `button` to the `header` it dosent work any longer. So `button` needs to be in `content` section to work. I guess it has something to do with `.mobile.changePage`

```
function refreshPage() {
 $.mobile.changePage(
 window.location.href,
 {
  allowSamePageTransition : true,
  transition              : 'none',
  showLoadMsg             : false,
  reloadPage              : true
 }
 );
}

$(window).load(function(){
 $('#refresh').on('click', function (e) {
    refreshPage();
 });
})
```

I'm calling the button using below code:

```
<div data-role="header">
    <button id="refresh" data-icon="refresh">Refresh</button>   
</div>
```

Comment: Are all your pages within one html file (many data-role="page" Divs, or are you linking to multiple html files?

Comment: This is just a single file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pagecontainer widget to get the **[active page](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-getActivePage)** and then refresh it with the **[change](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change)** method:

```
function refreshPage() {
  var curPageID = $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "getActivePage" ).prop("id");
  $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#" + curPageID, { 
    allowSamePageTransition : true,
  });
}
```

Also instead of $(window).load(function(){... use the jQM pagecreate event

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#page2", function(){ 
   $('#refresh').on('click', function (e) {
      refreshPage();
   });
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7u4jb22d/)**

In the demo, navigate to page 2 and then click refresh.

Comment: This worked for me; still, it does not refresh deep enough to execute ajax calls and other javascript updates (just like Ctr+F5 for example). Any idea on how i'd go for a 'deep' refresh? Thank you so much.

Comment: @CarlosGarcia You would have to post your code. It probably depends on which page events you use...